# Flink Streaming: How to process each event with all events of the last 30 days?

Tags: apache-flink

On a keyed stream, I would like to compute a window function once per new incoming event, immediately as soon as the new event arrives, while providing it with the context of all earlier events of this key from within the last 30 days as an iterator.

The expected behavior is similar to that of a sliding window with 30 days length and 1 nanosecond slide, computing the window function only once per incoming event.

I cannot see how to map this behavior on top of the built-in Tumbling/Sliding/Session windows with/without Triggers/Evictors, etc.

Can anybody help? Or does this require to write my own Window Assigner or my own keyed state handling?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, it is not easy to model your use case with the window primitives that Flink provides.

The best solution I can think of is to implement a custom operator (`OneInputStreamOperator`). This is a fairly low-level interface which has access to record timestamps, watermarks, and state (many of Flink's built-in operators are based on that interface). When a new record is received, the operator would put it into a priority queue which is ordered by timestamp, remove all elements earlier than 30 days, and evaluate the function over the remaining elements in the queue.

Note, the queue should be registered as managed state to make the operator fault-tolerant. If you want to use event time, you can only do the evaluate and drop data when a watermark is received.

When implementing the `OneInputStreamOperator` interface, it might help to peek at Flink's built-in operators, such as `StreamFilter` or one of the more complex ones.

The custom operator can be applied on a `DataStream` or `KeyedStream` (obtained by `DataStream.keyBy()`) using the `transform()` method.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me into the right direction. I am impressed by how easy it is to add powerful custom transformations. Here are some details on how I achieved the solution (skipping the managed state thing for now): extend AbstractStreamOperator with OneInputStreamOperator (see e.g. StreamFilter for examplary method implementations), and then apply your custom class instance to the stream via transform(...). Btw: this use case is quite common in e.g. behavioral analytics where you group by customer-id and want to react to each single new event immediately, depending on the history.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I extended my answer pointing to the `transform()` method and the `StreamFilter` class.

Comment: @cubiclettuce please share the sample code if you have solved this. I have to achieve same task. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So if I understand, we need to define a RichFunction, that will have maintain, PriorityQueue as a managed Value state. Whenever new element arrives, we take the last 30 days element while removing others from priority queue, do some calculation on 30days data and return that from RichFunction. So for every element arriving in stream, we emit this calculated value. @FabianHueske

Comment: That brings me to why we cannot just use the RichMapFunction.